# How to properly write kets

Tags: bug

I noticed asking various questions regarding quantum physics, that sometimes, the latex command \ket works ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29443/adding-3-electron-spins/), for example), and other times, it does not, and I am obliged to use \left | \psi \right>. Is there a special way to enable its use or did I miss something ?

Comment: [Modified guidance in 2020](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12798/44126)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source for [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/29472/44126) to the question you link includes, at the top,

```
 $\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
```

while [this other answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/29552/44126)
includes, between "the three vectors" and the first displayed equation,

```
 $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
```

So on that page both `$\ket\psi$` and `$\Ket\psi$` do what you want, but the spacing for `\Ket` is better because that author used `\left` and `\right`.

Moral of story: the definition is brief, so include it yourself if it makes your life easier.

Comment: Great, I didn't know we could define new commands inside posts ! I'll sure use it. By the way, how do you look at the source of other posts ?

Comment: Just beware of the fact that [`renewcommand` can be dangerous](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/should-we-indicate-the-use-of-renewcommand-in-the-help-center/6952#6952)

Comment: @Frotaur I clicked "edit" but didn't change anything to see the source.

Comment: That renewcommand explains why I was able to use \ket in some places but not others... Good to know

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn `|` and `\lvert` were not the same height...

Comment: @KyleKanos This is [no longer the case](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12798/the-scope-of-newcommand-changed). New and renewed MathJax commands are now scoped to individual posts and thus the danger listed there is no longer present.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the other two answers: the bra-ket angles both have unicode incarnations, `⟨` and `⟩`, and they are both rendered correctly by MathJax. Thus, if you type

```
$⟨a|b⟩$
```

it will render correctly. (On the other hand, this only works for the single-size version, i.e. `\right⟩` won't work.) My solution is to have those characters hardwired into my software keyboard, and it really speeds up typing.

In addition, this usage is directly in the spirit of [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown): having a lightweight source which renders into a nice formatting, but which is also human-readable directly from the source.

That said, it is important to remark that this usage is exclusive to MathJax and it does not work under standard TeX renderers. (In fact, MathJax will correctly render a bunch of off-track unicode symbols, like ≠, ±, ≃, ° and [so on](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_math_operators.html), that will send (La)TeX into a belly-up spin.) As such, I consider it impolite to use these characters when editing other people's posts.

---

Finally, a word of caution: **all the posts on a page share the same MathJax environment**, and in particular this means that **any commands that you define or `renew` can and will affect other posts on the same page**. This has been [discussed before on this meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/should-we-indicate-the-use-of-renewcommand-in-the-help-center), with the specific point that `renewcommand` should not be used on this site.

Defining a new command for `\ket`s and `\bra`s is not terrible, partly because even if other people on the same thread define it differently, you wouldn't expect real conflicts in the output. However, it's important to keep in mind that *any* use of `\newcommand`, particularly beyond the simplest, mildest, most standard definitions, can produce unexpected behaviour like e.g. [on this thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7297/mathjax-rendering-bk-differently-in-question-display-and-edit-modes).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source, you see that they include

`\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}`

in their LaTeX. This defines a command `\ket` that makes a ket. So you have to define it on your own.